# Is there any relation between strabismus and mathematical or scientific ability?

Tags: biographical-details, mathematics-social-history

By looking at the portraits of prominent mathematicians and scientists of the previous centuries it seems like they have a higher incidence of strabismus than the general population of today.
Are there any papers on the rate of strabismus among (prominent) scientists that compare it to that of the rest of the population?

Here is kind of an update on this:
A gene mutation that causes blindness also appears to be associated with above-average intelligence according to this [article](https://neurosciencenews.com/cord7-gene-iq-20550/)

Comment: Could you provide some numbers here, like what portion of portraits had strabismus; was it higher among portraits of scientists than all portraits and if so, by how much? How many portraits did you examine?

Comment: @MoisheKohan     Maybe 9 out of 35 scientists on the portraits seem to suffer from strabismus including Johann Bernoulli and Newton(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Bernoulli#/media/File:Johann_Bernoulli2.jpg https://artsandculture.google.com/asset/portrait-of-isaac-newton-john-vanderbank-1694-1739/lAF1tDYLsfMyNQ)

Comment: My suggestion is to make a similar analysis of portraits of bishops (another group whose occupation also required quite a bit of reading). One possible conjecture is that what you observed is more related to vision problems due to excessive reading in suboptimal conditions. BTW, I do not think causes of strabismus are well-understood.

Comment: @MoisheKohan From the few that I have seen I doubt it that they have such high incidence of strabismus(it may also be the case that the painter doesn't draw their strabismus). Perhaps a better way to see if there is any relation between mathematical/scientific ability and strabismus is to make a statistical analysis of modern mathematicians and scientists and their incidence of strabismus.

Comment: @GEP I appreciate your "better way to see"....